# Interceptor not exists issue when running setup:upgrade command in magento 2

Tags: setup-upgrade, interceptor, magento2.4.5p1

When i run setup upgrade command i got the following error

```
  Class "Vendor_Name\Subscription\Test\Command\DispatchEventOOSProduct\Interceptor" does not exist
```

I tried to remove the contents from the generated folder. but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing suggests that there is an issue with a generated class in your Magento 2 installation.

Here are some steps you can try to resolve the issue:

1. First, make sure that the class Vendor_Name\Subscription\Test\Command\DispatchEventOOSProduct\Interceptor actually exists in your codebase. Check that the file exists at the correct location and that the namespace and class names are correct.
2. Check that the class is being generated properly. Run the following command from your Magento 2 root directory:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   ```

This command will compile the dependency injection configuration for your Magento 2 installation, which includes generating some classes. Check the output of this command for any errors related to the Vendor_Name\Subscription\Test\Command\DispatchEventOOSProduct\Interceptor class.

3. If the above steps do not work, try deleting the contents of the var/generation directory and then re-run the php bin/magento setup:di:compile command. This will force Magento 2 to regenerate all of the generated classes, which may fix the issue.
4. If none of the above steps work, you may need to dig deeper into the code to determine the root cause of the issue. Look for any code that may be overriding the Vendor_Name\Subscription\Test\Command\DispatchEventOOSProduct class or any of its dependencies.

I hope this helps you resolve the issue!